# Accessing python SimpleHTTPServer from outside Virtual Box

Tags: python, networking, localhost, virtualbox, simplehttpserver

I'm running a python SimpleHTTPServer inside a virtual box. Is it possible to access it from the host machine?
Running ipconfig in my host gave me the following address. I tried using this in the browser of my host but that doesn't seem to work.
Should i be looking at a different IP address?

```
  $> ipconfig

    Windows IP Configuration


    Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

       Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

    Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

       Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
       Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : xx:xx:xx:xxxx:xxx:xxxx
       IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.99.1
       Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
       Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Comment: make sure you use the right port

Comment: you need to use bridged adaper in the vm config(probably)... then use that ip address...

Comment: @njzk2 I was using 8000, the default one that it opens on. Is that correct?

Comment: 172.0.0.1:8000 or 0.0.0.0:800

Comment: @JoranBeasley Tried that. Didn't work! Another problem with that is it doesn't allow me to access wi-fi inside virtual-box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Port forwarding in virtual box helped solve the problem.